# Is it possible to remove a drive from zfs?

Tags: zfs, truenas

I have a zfs raid-z1 with too much storage volume. I thought of taking out one volume.

Is it possible to remove a drive from a zfs raid storage?

thx for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this is not possible in your situation.

For other ZFS best practices and limitations, take a look at **[this blog post](http://nex7.blogspot.com/2013/03/readme1st.html)**.